# Group the variable according to its value and get a histogram

Tags: r, grouping, histogram, intervals

I'm trying to group the variable according to its values and get a histogram.

For example, this is my data:

```
r <-c(1,899,1,2525,763,3,2,2,1863,695,9,4,2876,1173,1156,5098,3,3876,1,1,
     3023,76336,13,003,9898,1,10,843,10546,617,1375,1,1,5679,1,21,1,13,6,28,1,14088,682)
```

I want to group r by its value, like: 1-5, 5-10, 10-100, 100-500 and more than 500. And then I want to get a histogram which the x axis is in the type of interval (1-5,5-10,10-100,100-500 and more than 500) . How to solve that?

If I want to use le package ggplot2, code as following:

```
ggplot(data=r, aes(x=r))+geom_histogram(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 100, 500,2000,Inf))
```

It dosen't work and R says that "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". And how to make the larges of bins are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R

```
r <-c(1,899,1,2525,763,3,2,2,1863,695,9,4,2876,1173,1156,5098,3,3876,1,1,5,
      3023,76336,13,003,9898,1,10,843,10546,617,1375,1,1,5679,1,21,1,13,6,28,1,14088,682)
cut.vals <- cut(r, breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 100, 500, Inf), right = FALSE)
xy <- data.frame(r, cut = cut.vals)
barplot(table(xy$cut))
```

Note that I added the `xy` variable to ease in comparing how values were grouped. You can directly put `cut.vals` into the `barplot(table())`.

[image]

To use `ggplot2`, you can pre-calculate all the bins and plot

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = cut)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

`geom_histogram`'s most common parameter that controls bin size is `binwidth`, which is constant for all bins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An I wanna know that if I use the ggplot2 with the "breaks" are defined as above, how to make the large of each bin are the same? Because if breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 100, 500, 100000), those first few bins are too narrow to see.