# Group observations in geom_histogram axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, histogram

A simple vector:

```
freq = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
```

And a simple histogram:

```
ggplot(data=as.data.frame(freq), aes(x=freq)) + geom_histogram()
```

How do I count all observations with value, for example, >= 4 and show as one bar?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess `aes(x = freq >= 4))` should work

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment. Just checked it, it works, but you have to specify the 'stat' parameter in geom_histogram:

```
require(ggplot2)
freq = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
ggplot(data=as.data.frame(freq), aes(x = freq >=4)) + geom_histogram(stat = 'count')
```

If you want to group by value, you can create 'cuts' as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289699/group-the-variable-according-to-its-value-and-get-a-histogram)

You can also create the cuts directly in ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=as.data.frame(freq), aes(x = cut(freq, c(1,2,3), include.lowest = TRUE))) + 
#you need to make sure that the cuts actually represent the intervals you want!! 
  geom_histogram(stat = 'count')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible way might be to replace all values >= 4 with 4 and then plot

```
freq[freq >=4] = 4
```